# why might findViewById() crash relativeLayout init command?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am writing a Chess app in Android Studio 3.0, and I want a PopupWindow to appear when the user clicks `btnPopUpWindow`, a button on the Chessboard layout.  Here' the chessboard layout XML:

**activity_chessboard.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="me.androidchess.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/chessboardlayout">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/popUpButton"
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Pop Up Menu"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The XML layout above is loaded by **Chessboard.java**.  Obviously, Chessboard would be the parent of the popup window, which is why I would want to use a RelativeLayout reference for the popup to see Chessboard.

**Chessboard.java**

```
public class Chessboard extends Activity {

Button btnPopUpWindow;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chessboard);

    btnPopUpWindow = findViewById(R.id.popUpButton);                       // This works
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.chessboardlayout);  // <--- CRASHES HERE!!!
    btnPopUpWindow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxqgtEewdfo

            gameTextArea.setText("Pop up Menu appears...");

        }
    });
}
```

Its that `relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.chessboardlayout);` line which crashes the app.

I am assuming that `findViewById()` is failing to locate the ID `chessboardlayout`, but I can't figure out why.  I can't find the `R.id` directory in Android Studio, but I notice that `chessboardlayout` appears in the drop-down options when I type out the command.  Plus I see the Id when I walk through the debugger.  So I assume the Id has been properly filed.

But when I follow the debugger, the `findViewById()` call returns null, which can't be good.  Specifically, an "*Unable to start activity*" exception is thrown by `performLaunchActivity()` in **ActivityThread.java**  No idea how that is happening.

I've read through the other `findViewById()` threads that pop up in StackOverview searches, and a lot of those issues seem to revolve around the item returned by `findViewById()` not matching the local variable `Button x = findViewById(R.id.TextFieldHere);` for example.  But that doesn't seem to be the case here... unless I don't understand how a RelativeLayout is supposed to work here...?  Any advice/insight is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `R.id.chessboardlayout` is an `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` so you cannot cast it to `RelativeLayout` or it will cause [ClassCastException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassCastException.html).

So if you still want to use RelativeLayout as root of your layout, change your `activity_chessboard.xml` to this:

**activity_chessboard.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="me.androidchess.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/chessboardlayout">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/popUpButton"
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Pop Up Menu"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your activity use the `findViewById()` normally.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_chessboard);
btnPopUpWindow = findViewById(R.id.popUpButton);                      
relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.chessboardlayout);
```